# Conditional to perform multiple comparisons doesn't work

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I've been having trouble with this python code. I just started coding and I can't figure out why it's not working. I can't get the loop to stop repeating. No matter what I input it initiates the add_item function. Any tips?

```
supply = { #Creates blank dictionary
}
print "Would you like to add anything to the list?"

def add_item(*args):     #Adds a item to the supply dictionary
    print "What would you like to add?"
    first_item = raw_input()
    print "How much does it cost?"
    first_price = raw_input()
    supply[first_item] = float(first_price)

response = raw_input()

while response == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
    if response == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES": #Added this because it wasn't working, didn't help
        add_item()
        print "Alright, your stock now reads:", supply
        print "Would you like to add anything else?"
        response = raw_input()
    elif response == "no" or "No" or "NO":
        print "Alright. Your stock includes:" 
        print supply
        break
    else:
        print "Sorry I didn't understand that. Your stock includes:" 
        print supply
        break

print "Press Enter to close"
end_program = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be confused on how `or` works.

Your original expression could be rewritten like this:

```
(response == "yes") or ("Yes") or ("YES")
```

That is, it measured the truth of three expressions: the equality expression,
and each of the two remaining string expressions. Both `"Yes"` and `"YES"` evaulate
as true, so you (more-or-less) have:

```
while (response == "yes") or True or True:
```

Since `"Yes"` always evaluates as true,
the while expression was always true.

Try:

```
while response in ( "yes" , "Yes" , "YES"):
```

Or, better still:

```
while response.lower() == "yes":
```

Comment: Hey! I have absolutely no memory of posting this, but thanks for the help! I can assure you, I've made significant progress in the last 4 years.

Comment: Haven't we all! I'm glad to have helped and glad that you've grown. Maybe you're ready to start *answering* questions now.